# How to setup AWS credentials in rails for development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to set up my credentials in development? I'm able to set up credentials in production because of heroku's configuration variables... but need help doing so if you're just testing app locally.

I have this in my `development.rb`

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

But, I'm not sure how to reference these ENV variables?

I created this `aws.yml` file in my **/config** folder

```
development:
  BUCKET_NAME: "somename"
  ACCESS_KEY_ID: "4205823951412980"
  SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "123141ABNCEFEHUDSL2309489850"
```

I thought if I matched the ENV name, it'll work? I guess thats not the case...

I made sure to include `aws.yml` to my `.ignore` file

```
/config/aws.yml
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem. Install the gem `gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]`, then 
just create and `.env' file and put the variables into it like this.

```
S3_BUCKET=YOURS3BUCKET
SECRET_KEY=YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE
```

Answer (score 1):

What I like to is create a **config.yml** on my **./config** directory.

then I tell the **./config/application.rb** I have a small block that loads the variables like

```
config.before_initialize do
  dev = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'config.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(dev)).each do |key,value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(dev)
end
```

Here is my **./config/config.yml**

```
BUCKET_NAME: "somename"
ACCESS_KEY_ID: "4205823951412980"
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "123141ABNCEFEHUDSL2309489850"
```

---

#### New Updates

Here is a copy of my #config/application.rb

```
#config/application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

    module Appname
      class Application < Rails::Application
        # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
        # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
        # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    
        # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
        # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
        # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    
        # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
        # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
        # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    
        # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
        config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    
        initializer 'setup_asset_pipeline', :group => :all  do |app|
          # We don't want the default of everything that isn't js or css, because it pulls too many things in
          app.config.assets.precompile.shift
    
          # Explicitly register the extensions we are interested in compiling
          app.config.assets.precompile.push(Proc.new do |path|
            File.extname(path).in? [
              '.html', '.erb', '.haml',                 # Templates
              '.png',  '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg',         # Images
              '.eot',  '.otf', '.svc', '.woff', '.ttf', # Fonts
            ]
          end)
        end
    
        I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
    
        config.before_initialize do
          dev = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'config.yml')
          YAML.load(File.open(dev)).each do |key,value|
            ENV[key.to_s] = value
          end if File.exists?(dev)
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Why is there a `.example` after `.yml`? Is this different than your `config.yml` file you create?

Comment: No the example is because you can share that file as with out it is usually in the .gitignore file

Comment: hmmm, I think I see what you're saying. I tested it out without creating a config.yml.example, and tried to push to heroku, but its saying that they can't find config.yml... because config.yml was not uploaded to my server (I put it in .gitignore). So because, its in gitignore, heroku needs to find a config.yml file? Which, it will search for config.yml.example instead?

Comment: Is that the purpose of any file that ends with a .example?

Comment: the `.example` is just so that you can show others how the file in the `.gitignore` looks like so that all variables match and you use that to create your file like `config.yml`. you would not put real values there just like you would not post them here

Comment: I tried, putting this `config.before_initilize do`  block right after `class Application < Rails::Application` but I'm getting a `uninitialized constant CONFIG (NameError)` error.

Comment: I appended my `config/application.rb` so you can see how I am using it. I hope that t his helps

Comment: hmmmm, I'm getting this error:  `'[]=': no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)` Any idea?

Comment: can you post what you have in the ./config/config.yml

Comment: Its what I have in my question post. I have nothing but just `development: and then following the key and values`

Comment: remove the line that says development and move everything else to the left 2 spaces

Comment: Now its saying that `'load_yaml_config': config/aws.yml is missing a section for 'development' (RuntimeError)`

Answer (score 1):

I like to use **Foreman** locally and store all my variables in a **.ENV** file. Plays well with Heroku and is easy to manage. Also in my case I have the following:

Under **config/initiliazers/aws.rb**

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'aws-sdk-resources'

# Rails.configuration.aws is used by AWS, Paperclip, and S3DirectUpload
Rails.configuration.aws = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml")).result)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys!
AWS.config(logger: Rails.logger)
AWS.config(Rails.configuration.aws)
```

**Under config/initializers/paperclip.rb**

```
# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3
if Rails.env.test?
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
    path: ":rails_root/public/paperclip/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:filename",
    storage: :filesystem
  )
else
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
    url: ':s3_domain_url',
    path: '/:class/:filename',
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: Rails.configuration.aws,
    s3_protocol: 'https'
  )
end
```

**Under config/aws.yml**

```
defaults: &defaults
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
test:
  <<: *defaults
  bucket: <%= ENV['AWS_TEST_BUCKET'] %>
development:
  <<: *defaults
  bucket: <%= ENV['AWS_TEST_BUCKET'] %>
production:
  <<: *defaults
  bucket: <%= ENV['AWS_BUCKET'] %>
```

Comment: Could you provide sample of " store all my variables in a .ENV file." and where you put the .ENV (or .env) file

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails, you can simply start your rails app with command line params. It is good to know the base case, where you know for sure that your params are indeed passed to your app:

ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABCDEFG SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secreTaccessKey BUCKET_NAME=dev-images rails s

I actually prefer to set an alias in env:

alias railss='ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABCDEFG SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secreTaccessKey BUCKET_NAME=dev-images rails s'

Comment: @Powers, you "don't think" or "it will not work"? I am running AWS this way on my multiple projects. You should try it one day before down-voting answers. A code or gem can fail, but if passing params from command line to the app fails then we are in big trouble. FYI, you can use this in your rake tasks too.

Comment: You're right, I thought you were setting Ruby constants, but you're right that environment variables can be set on the command line like you suggested.  StackOverflow isn't letting me reverse my downvote, sorry.

Comment: @Powers, well, at least now you know. Please be careful with down-voting next time.